# Runtime Error when soving the problems of leetcode 5. Longest Palindromic Substring

Tags: c, runtime

I just tried to use dp method to solve the longest palindromic substring problem, this is the souce code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
char* longestPalindrome(char *s) 
{
    int length=strlen(s);
    if(length == 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if(length == 1)
    {
        return s;
    }
    int dp[length][length];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<length;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<length;j++)
        {
            if (i>=j)
            {
                dp[i][j]=1; 
            }
        }
    }

    int maxlen=1;
    int len_now=0;
    int start=0,fin=0;
    for(len_now=1;len_now<length;len_now++)
    {
        for(i=0;i+len_now<length;i++)
        {
            j=i+len_now;
            if(s[i] != s[j])
            {
                dp[i][j]=0;
            }
            else
            {
                dp[i][j]=dp[i+1][j-1];
                if(dp[i][j])
                {
                    if(len_now+1>maxlen)
                    {
                        maxlen=len_now+1;
                        start=i;
                        fin=j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*char result[maxlen];
    strncpy(result, s+start,maxlen);
    result[maxlen]='\0';
    char *tao=result;
    return tao;*/
    //I firstly tried to use strncpy to copy the result into a new string, it works on my own computer(using mingw5), but it return NULL when I test it through leetcode, and then I find this solution as below:
    char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(maxlen));
    for(i = start,j = 0; j < maxlen; i++,j++)
    {
        result[j] = s[i];
    }
    result[j] = '\0';
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    char *s="abcba";
    char *p;
    p=longestPalindrome(s);
    printf("%s\n",p);
}
```

but when I submited it, runtime erreur occurs, does anyone knows how to improve it? (in the documentation of leetcode, it says dp solution is accepted, so I think it should work)

also, I have a question that why when I return a char result[] type, when I tested on leetcode, it return NULL.

thanks a lot

Comment: You should initialize `dp` correct.

Comment: And quote the runtime error - otherwise you're just saying "something happened that I didn't expect"

Comment: What is the variable `fin` doing? You set it, but never use it.